# in_array es falso siempre

Tags: php

tengo este código para obtener la disponibilidad de una URL cualquiera, pero al utilizar el *in_array()*, siempre que comparo me da un resultado de FALSE. Quisiera saber qué estoy haciendo mal o es en cuanto al tratamiento del tipo de variable.

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.example.com/');

//print_r(sscanf( $headers[0], 'HTTP/%*d.%*d %d'));
$accept = array( 200, 301, 302 );
if(in_array($headers[0], $accept)){
    echo "Disponible";
} else {
    echo "No disponible";
}
```

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal los valores de **headers** son strings

Comment: El [manual dice](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php) que: *Devuelve un array indexado o asociativo con las cabeceras, **o FALSE en caso de fallo**.*. Haz un `var_dump($headers);` y si te imprime `false` ya sabes lo que es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el Manual, la información de `get_headers` viene así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:13 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
    [3] => Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
    [4] => ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
    [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [6] => Content-Length: 438
    [7] => Connection: close
    [8] => Content-Type: text/html
)
```

Como puedes apreciar, el código del estado viene con otros datos: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` para el código `200`.

Por lo tanto, tu código nunca va a funcionar.

Esto lo puedes resolver de varias formas.

La más simple sería usando `cURL`.

Algo así:

```
$url="http://www.example.com";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($handle);

$responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$accept = array( 200, 301, 302 );
if(in_array($responseCode, $accept)){
    echo "Disponible";
} else {
    echo "No disponible";
}

curl_close($handle);
```

---

Si fuera la url del propio script se puede obtener el código de respuesta con el uso de  [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.http-response-code.php).

---

Otra opción sería extraer el código mediante expresiones regulares. Pero habría que ver si las respuestas son todas estándar.

---

Y otra opción sería hacer una búsqueda *parcial* de los valores de tu array en la clave [0]  del header. O sea buscar si en los valores como `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` *se encuentra el valor `200` o el `301` o el `302`.

Comment: Con este código si pude recuperar el valor que quiero, pero tengo una duda con respecto al `ìn_array()`, según lo que pude ver son como mínimo 2 parámetros, un mixed y un array, qué podría modificar en el mixed para que el `header[0]` sea tratado correctamente, la única opción es la que propones?. Gracias por el código.

Comment: Y otra observación más, el código `$response = curl_exec($handle);` creo que no está haciendo nada o sí? no utilizas la variable, qué función el `curl_exec()`?

Comment: @Thephoenix25 el uso de `curl_exec` es fundamental, pues es la función que ejecuta la petición [ver aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php). En cuanto a [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)  el 1er parámetro es el valor a buscar. Si optas por hacerlo como lo tienes ahora, tendrías que tener un array con los datos como vienen en el `header[0]`, o sea: `$accept=array('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', 'otro...', 'otro...');`  aún así sería muy precario, porque `HTTP/1.1` podría ser otro valor. La mejor forma de obtener únicamente el código numérico es mediante `cURL`.